# Why is the definite article removed in this example, but not the other?

Tags: definite-article

> The folks who run the Converse brand understand that in order to
>   provide a meaningful experience customer experience, sometimes they
>   just need to stand back and leave **(the)** customers alone.

In this book, Marketing: An Introduction, the book opted to omit the definite article. I want to know why.

If you were to say,

> Don't argue with the customer. The customer is always right.

Why did we not omit the definite article here though we are referring to any customer, not a defined one?

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors at play.

In the second example *customer* is singular. So you have to refer either to *a customer* or *the customer*. You can't say: *Customer is always right*.

Also, *the customer* is used to mean customers in general, not any specific customer or group of customers. We do the same with descriptions such as *the consumer* and *the tax payer* to refer to all people who consume/pay taxes.

But in the first example *customers* is plural. Here it is possible to speak either of *the customers* or just *customers*.

*Customers*, without the article, refers to customers in general, any customers, all customers - and not any specific group of customers.

We would use the same construction - without the article - if we were talking of *visitors* or *football fans*.

> > Visitors are asked not to litter.
> >
> > Tax payers are up in arms.

On the other hand, to speak of *the customers* is to refer to specific customers, who have been mentioned earlier. This description implies a smaller, defined group, which is not the intention of the author.